# Working but ugly Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that functions correctly **but** doesn't look well written.

```
$($($(value).find("td")[4]).find("span")[0]).text()
```

I am locating some specific values in some html and pulling them out. The issue is that when I find a elemnt and use "[4]" I have to wrap it as another jQuery object before I can use find again.

Obvously this code looks odd with three $'s on the left.

Is my line of code acceptable or am I doing something fundementally wrong.

Thank you

Comment: provide html, that will help us better to judge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write that like below,

```
$(value).find("td:eq(4) span:first").text()
```

You are mixing up plain `javascript` more, that's not wrong. But this above code will look quite cleaner.

For more reference,

- [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)
- [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Comment: `eq` "reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index". Please, read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(value).find("td:nth-child(5) span:first").text();
```